# Python import package from specific installed directory

Tags: python-2.7, module

I have the same Python package installed in many different locations in Mac OS. Due to specific reasons, I want to import the module from a specific installed directory.

Can anyone suggest the best way for doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: This is a duplicate and you should be able to find your answer already on the site. For example, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Thanks nbryans. But that resource is not helpful in my case. In particular, I have two versions of package in different locations under site-packages. I am trying to import one specific version but by default python loads another version. Not sure how to import another version. I can do this using virtualenv, but in my case I want another alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this and add the directory that the configuration file is sitting in to the Python load path, and then just do a normal import, assuming you know the name of the file in advance, in this case "config".

Messy, but it works.

```
configfile = '~/config.py'

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser(configfile)))

import config
```